# Take differences in two arrays and record their number in a third array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

So I have been having an extremely hard time trying to figure out this issue. All of my code currently works except for my last module where I am trying to compare the two arrays for differences and record the question number into a new array. I'm not really sure how to set it up. Any help will be appreciated.

The main issue is with the array incorrect I am creating. I do not know how to set up a blank array that gets bigger as values are entered. Unless I am just really messing that concept up. I have the issues currently commented out while I was trying different things.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int COLS = 20;
void input_data(char [], int);
void compare_data(char [], int, char [], int);

int main()
{
    char letters[COLS];
    char answers[] = { 'A', 'D', 'B', 'B',
                       'C', 'B', 'A', 'B',
                       'C', 'D', 'A', 'C',
                       'D', 'B', 'D', 'C',
                       'C', 'A', 'D', 'B'};

    input_data(letters, COLS);
    compare_data(letters, COLS, answers, COLS);
}

void input_data(char letter[], int size)
{
    cout << "Please enter the student's answers for each of the questions. \n";
    cout << "Press Enter after typing each answer. \n";
    cout << "Please enter only an A, B, C, or D for each question. \n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Question " << i << ": ";
        cin >> letter[i - 1];
        while (letter[i - 1] != 'A' && 
                letter[i - 1] != 'B' &&
                letter[i - 1] != 'C' &&
                letter[i - 1] != 'D')
        {
            cout << "Please enter only A, B, C, or D \n";
            cout << "Question " << i << ":";
            cin >> letter[i - 1];
        }
    }
}

void compare_data(char letter[], int size, char answer[], int cols)
{
    int ans_correct = 0;
    int ans_wrong = 0;
    //int incorrect[20];
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if (letter[i] == answer[i])
            ans_correct += 1;
        else
        {
            ans_wrong += 1;
            //incorrect[i-1] = i;
        }
    }

    if (ans_correct >= 15)
        cout << "The student passed the exam. \n";
    else
        cout << "The student did not pass the exam. \n";

    cout << "Correct Answers: " << ans_correct << endl;
    cout << "Incorrect Answers: " << ans_wrong << endl << endl;

    cout << "Questions that were answered incorrectly: \n";
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        //cout << incorrect[i-1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)` -- Loops using `<=` and `i` being used as a subscript is a red flag.  And yes, you are accessing your array out-of-bounds.  In C+, arrays start at index 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a working version. It does not grow the incorrect array, since that would be overkill for such a small operation, and you are using a constant 'COLS' anyhow.

Since it is a c++ tagged question, if you really want a dynamic array, why not use std::vector? You **can** do similar things with C-style arrays, but it is very messy.

```
void compare_data(char letter[], int size, char answer[], int cols)
{
   int ans_correct = 0;
   int ans_wrong = 0;
   //setup array big enough to hold all answers
   //and initialize to 0
   int incorrect[COLS] = {0};
   // Your original code had wrong loop limits!
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
     if (letter[i] == answer[i])
        ans_correct += 1;
     else
     {
        //Fill in incorrect only on wrong answers!
        //But the number you want to record is the
        //the number of the question, which is i + 1
        incorrect[ans_wrong] = i + 1;
        ans_wrong += 1;
    }
}

if (ans_correct >= COLS/2)
    cout << "The student passed the exam. \n";
else
    cout << "The student did not pass the exam. \n";

cout << "Correct Answers: " << ans_correct << endl;
cout << "Incorrect Answers: " << ans_wrong << endl << endl;

cout << "Questions that were answered incorrectly: \n";
//Even if the array is bigger, you don't wnat to output the
//unused parts
for (int i = 0; i < ans_wrong; i++)
{
    cout << incorrect[i] << endl;
}
}
```